# Check for printf in call instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

```
 %1 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([22 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 7) #3
```

For the above instruction, how can I check whether the call instruction contains printf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the name of the called function:

```
bool isPrintfCall(CallInst &C) {
   auto *F = C.getCalledFunction();
   auto isPrintf = (F->getName() == "printf");
   return isPrintf;
}
```

Comment: The C.getCalledFunction() returns null in LLVM 8.0 any trick for the new version of LLVM

Comment: I shouldn't return null unless you're calling an anonymous function I think.